# What record formats are available in Google Ion not listed in core formats?

Tags: android, audio, record

Looks like the only way to record something is the narrowband codec at 12kbps and 8khz sample rate. Surely audiorecord isnt limited by these rates is it? Where do I look? HTC sapphire source?

Answer (score 0):

AudioRecord can go up to 44.1khz at least. Just use 44100

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html